# Easy to spread caulking - window weather proofing

Tags: windows, exterior, caulking

I want to go around the exterior of my windows, etc with some caulking.  I have some now that I used in the bathroom but it doesn't spread that easy or lay a decent bead.  I know when I was growing up and helping my dad build houses we had stuff that would lay a good bead and I could push it into the joints without making a giant mess.  Well I want to make doing the exterior as easy as possible so;  Do you know of any good exterior caulking that is easy to put on and spread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the packaging on the caulk you used for your bathroom. From what you described, it was most likely silicone caulk, which is more difficult to work with than other types of caulk. Silicone requires alcohol rather than water for cleanup. I'd try acrylic caulk, which is the most common choice for exterior applications.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Doresoom, you need to use an acrylic mixed with silicone caulk. It is normally labeled as door, window and trim exterior caulk. This type of caulk is water clean-up, easy to smooth out and paintable when dry. Bathroom tub and tile silicone caulk is not paintable, and you;re right, much harder to work with.